# Removing a letters located between to specific string

Tags: javascript, uri, fragment-identifier

I want to make sure that the URL I get from `window.location` does not already contain a specific fragment identifier already.  If it does, I must remove it.  So I must search the URL, and find the string that starts with `mp-` and continues until the end URL or the next `#` (Just in case the URL contains more than one fragment identifier).

#### Examples of inputs and outputs:

```
www.site.com/#mp-1 --> www.site.com/
www.site.com#mp-1 --> www.site.com
www.site.com/#mp-1#pic --> www.site.com/#pic
```

#### My code:

(that obviously does not work correctly)

```
var url = window.location;
if(url.toLowerCase().indexOf("#mp-") >= 0){
   var imgString = url.substring(url.indexOf('#mp-') + 4,url.indexOf('#'));
   console.log(imgString);
}
```

Any idea how to do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use regular expressions:

```
var url = window.location;
var imgString = url.replace(/(#mp-[^#\s]+)/, "");
```

It removes from URL hash anything from `mp-` to the char before `#`.

[Regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/nU7jF8/1)

Answer (score 5):

Something like this? This uses a regular expression to filter the unwanted string.

```
var inputs = [
  "www.site.com/#mp-1",
  "www.site.com#mp-1",
  "www.site.com/#mp-1#pic"
];

inputs = inputs.map(function(input) {
  return input.replace(/#mp-1?/, '');
});

console.log(inputs);
```

Output:

```
["www.site.com/", "www.site.com", "www.site.com/#pic"]
```

jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/tghuye75/

The regex I used `/#mp-1?/` removes any strings like `#mp-` or `#mp-1`. For a string of unknown length until the next hashtag, you can use `/#mp-[^#]*` which removes `#mp-`, `#mp-1`, and `#mp-somelongstring`.

Comment: Note that it only works if the string to be removed is exactly `#mp-1` or `#mp-`.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `.replace` to replace a regular expression matching ("#mp-" followed by 0 or more non-`#` characters) with the empty string. If it's possible there are multiple segments you want to remove, just add a `g` flag to the regex.

```
url = url.replace(/#mp-[^#]*/, '');
```

Answer (score 1):

The window.location has the hash property so... window.location.hash

The most primitive way is to declare

```
var char_start, char_end
```

and find two "#" or one and the 2nd will be end of input.

with that... you can do what you want, the change of window.location.hash will normally affect the browser adress.

Good luck!